# How to PHP Relative paths?

Tags: php

I am trying to include my JS file, which includes all core Javascript files in a PHP file, but I cannot get the relative/root path to work, so I could use it across all the pages which are located in sub folders etc.

Here is the structure:

[image]

In Dashboard I have this:

[image]

In folder `family` I have a file called `addJob.php` where I am trying to include a file `bottomscripts.php` which is in `Dashboard/PHP/views/JS_includes/`.

I have to use these across all the pages so how can I set the path?
I tried using this:

```
<?php
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/Hoidja.ee/Dashboard/');

echo ('<script src='.BASE_URL.'assets/js/gsap/main-gsap.js"></script>');
echo ('<script src='.BASE_URL.'assets/js/resizeable.js"></script>');
echo ('<script src='.BASE_URL.'assets/js/neon-api.js"></script>');
echo ('<script src='.BASE_URL.'assets/js/neon-custom.js"></script>');

?>
```

But this gives me forbidden error. I also tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but this gives me failed to load local resource.

```
<?php
$basePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Hoidja.ee/Dashboard/';

echo ('<script src='.$basePath.'assets/js/gsap/main-gsap.js"></script>');
echo ('<script src='.$basePath.'assets/js/resizeable.js"></script>');
echo ('<script src='.$basePath.'assets/js/neon-api.js"></script>');
echo ('<script src='.$basePath.'assets/js/neon-custom.js"></script>');

?>
```

Comment: All your `src` values are missing the opening `"`.

Comment: Are you able to open e.g. `http://localhost/Hoidja.ee/Dashboard/assets/js/gsap/main-gsap.js` in your browser?

Comment: @mapek yes I can.

Comment: @lafor I fixed that and the same issue.

Comment: First ensure that the lettercase used in  directory and file names is exactly correct. i.e. 'js' and 'JS' are not the same on linux. To debug this I would have a simple javascript file ('hello world'). I would start with it in the document root and set a path to it using the above code. Check it loads. Move it down the path until you get an error. Why do this? 1) I know it must work in document root and is easy to fix if it doesn't. ) After that it is just a matter of checking paths and names. It doesn't take long to do.

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks for the suggestion. will look into it.